# Using putObject command to aliased bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I've got a script that uploads files perfectly fine into buckets.  However, one particular bucket has been given a cname so that it can be accessed directly, apparently it has been assigned this using CloudFront.

I'm no expert in this field, but basically, instead of accessing the bucket via:
http://mybucket.mysite.com.s3.amazonaws.com/thing.txt, it allows you to access it via:
http://mybucket.mysite.com/thing.txt

It performs the put fine by the looks of it, when I do a response on the callback, it says it's all done but the last element in the array swaps the bucket and the endpoint around, so it looks like this: https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket.mysite.com/thing.txt

However, when I use any other bucket it uploads correctly and returns the correct ObjectURL.

Having had a search around google and this site, I can't seem to find a solution so any help would be magic.

I'm using an older version of the AWS PHP 2 sdk, currently using 2.2.1.

Edit: even stranger still, when I pass the bucket through the isValidBucketName method, it returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else ever encounters this issue, the problem was that when executing the put, the SDK automatically assumes that you are trying to connect to a bucket in the US region.  So I needed to specify what region the bucket is in, in my case EU_WEST_1, so when you set up your config array, be sure to provide this value, eg.

```
$config = array(
    'key' => 'your-key'
,   'secret' => 'your-secret'
,   'region' => Region::EU_WEST_1
);
```

Being sure to include the Aws\Common\Enum\Region in the class.